# nested ui-router $location binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some problem with binding when i use ui-router. I am trying to make the app modular and keep it clean and simple.
I have the following app.js

```
// main routing - index.html
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'pages/main.html'
        })
        .state('cars', {
            url: '/cars',
            templateUrl: 'pages/Cars_model/main.html'
        })
        .state('cars.audi', {
            url: '/audi',
            templateUrl: 'pages/Cars_model/audi.html'
        })
        .state('cars.ford', {
            url: '/ford',
            templateUrl: 'pages/Cars_model/ford.html'
        })
});
app.controller('indexController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isIndexPage = function() {
        return $location.path() === '/';
    }
});
app.controller('carsCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    if($location.path() === '/cars/audi')
    {
        $scope.pageHeader = "AUDI";
        $scope.curentMenu = "Best Cars";
        $scope.title = "Audi Specs";
    }
    if($location.path() === '/cars/ford')
    {
        $scope.pageHeader = "FORD";
        $scope.curentMenu = "Best Cars";
        $scope.title = "Ford Specs";
    }
});
```

and the file where i want to use binding

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="carsCtrl">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>{{pageHeader}}</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- The first row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sd-12">                
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/cars">{{curentMenu}}</a></li>
                <li class="active">{{pageHeader}}</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when i load the page the binding work only once, for the second i have to refresh the page.

I am not sure if i used the corect logic

```
if($location.path() === '/cars/ford')
```

Comment: where is your ui-view?

Comment: down in the upper page ( <div ui-view></div>) where is the carsController too

Comment: wait, this HTML is one of your templates, and you are declaring the `carsCtrl` both in the parent and in the template?

Comment: only in the template

Comment: Your route "/cars/ford" has no matching state :)

Comment: I'm having a problem recreating the routing structure you are using in the code here.  Can you post a [mcve] of the problem, using something like [plunker](http://plnkr.co)?

Comment: Nio, what do you mean no matching state?

Comment: your code has `$location.path() === '/cars/ford'` but your route has the url as `/ford`.  Unless there is something in your code that you aren't showing here, there seems to be a disconnect.  On top of that, it's generally not a good idea to use the same controller for more than one view, for a variety of reasons (such as the fact that controllers aren't singletons);  if you have values you need to access from more than one view, a service is the better choice.

Comment: i write an example similar what i have 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gA2zqNDCNMW62cm2GsIm?p=info)

The idea is when changing from audi to ford in the menu the binding does not work

Comment: **what bindings don't work**?  in the plunker you posted, your ford.html and audi.html pages don't have any bindings, they have a single line of static HTML each.

Comment: I *assume* what you are trying to do is change the properties on the `cars.html` page when the child page is changed.  that won't work the way you have written this, since you have only set the values in the constructor of the `carsCtrl` function, which will only run the first time that page is navigated to.  Again, if you are trying to share data between different views, or from the child to the parent, you should use a service.

Comment: you *might* be able to use `emit()` to tell the parent controller that it should check the status of those properties again, but that assumes a controller for each child page.

Comment: Yes, that is what i am trying to do. To change some properties like: <li class="active">{{pageHeader}}</li> in the parent class when the child is changed.  I will look how this emit() work. Thanks @Claies

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution

Using

```
 ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"
```

in the menu solve the problem

```
<a ui-sref="cars.audi" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Audi</a>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gA2zqNDCNMW62cm2GsIm)